# Error when trying to run `flutter upgrade`

Tags: git, flutter

I am trying to both upgrade my Flutter SDK and also change my Flutter channel to `master`, but I encounter the following error:

```
git: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
git:    examples/catalog/android/build.gradle
git:    examples/catalog/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
git:    packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle
git: Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
git: Aborting
Switching channels failed with error code 1.
```

Why does this happen and how do fix this?

Comment: Revert/discard all changes on flutter repo and them try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade to flutter 1.0 if I have local changes in my FlutterRoot folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918412/how-to-upgrade-to-flutter-1-0-if-i-have-local-changes-in-my-flutterroot-folder)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This occurs because the files have been changed locally. This means that the version you have on your machine is different from the one on GitHub.

The easiest way to fix this is using `--force`:

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

This will *override* any of the mismatched files. Make sure that you have no progress that would be lost by this (e.g. when you are working on a PR for [`flutter`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter)).

---

Another way of resolving this is to delete the files from your device and then execute `flutter upgrade`. This will resolve the Git error because it will just fetch the files from the internet again.

To do this head to your Flutter directory and remove the files. E.g. if your Flutter SDK directory was `F:/data/flutter`, you would need to remove the following files:

- `F:/data/flutter/examples/catalog/android/build.gradle`
- `F:/data/flutter/examples/catalog/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
- `F:/data/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle`

Answer (score 14):

These commands executed from the Flutter install directory should get you back to a working state

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

Now `flutter upgrade`, `flutter channel ...`, ... should work fine again.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Comment: I've update my old answer to this type of questions to address the new wiki section. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918412/how-to-upgrade-flutter-if-i-have-local-changes-in-my-flutterroot-folder/53918441#53918441

Comment: `git clean -xfd` was all I had to do, then flutter upgrade worked.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot leave comments yet (my current rep is 15), but I wanted to help.

I tried following @Günter Zöchbauer instructions (all merits go to him), but I had a file locked and couldn't move forward. My IDE was not open, not sure what was locking dart.exe file.

I had the following warning message:

```
$ git clean -xfd
Unlink of file 'bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
```

I resolved the issue by unlocking the dart.exe file using [IOBIT file unlocker](https://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php#) (freeware). There might be other software that unlocks files, or maybe some Windows commands.

Instructions:

- Download the software, install it, and run it
- Browse or drag-N-drop the locked file (in my case within the flutter
  folder: 'bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe')
- Click Unlock
- Done.

[image: Screenshot of unlocked file]

[Screenshot photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGtGK.png)

Now you can run @Günter Zöchbauer suggested commands (thanks Gunter!):

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor

flutter upgrade
flutter channel <yourChannelHere>
```

I was able to follow @Günter Zöchbauer commands and instructions.
I successfully upgrade flutter and changed to  channel:

```
$ flutter channel dev
    Switching to flutter channel 'dev'...
    git: From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
    git:    c5e47992c7..c37fe7c4fa  master     -> origin/master
    git: Switched to branch 'dev'
    Successfully switched to flutter channel 'dev'.
    To ensure that you're on the latest build from this channel, run 'flutter upgrade'
```

After changing channel, it was suggested to run 'flutter upgrade' again.

This solved my issue, I hope it will help you as well.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Flutter base directory ('/path/to/flutter/bin/') and after this execute this command:

```sh
git add --all
git commit -am "my-switch-commit"
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
flutter channel
```