# Flutter SDK version issue

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart

Ill explain original issue and then some details I figured out while I was trying to fix it

I am trying to build signed apk in VS for flutter

`flutter build appbundle`

And got this error

`The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.`
`Because workmanager 0.5.1 requires Flutter SDK version >=2.5.0 and no versions of workmanager match >0.5.1 <0.6.0, workmanager ^0.5.1 is forbidden. So, because pocket_mentor depends on workmanager ^0.5.1, version solving failed.`

I was trying to run

`flutter upgrade`

But got this error

`ProcessException: Process exited abnormally: fatal: no such branch: 'stable' Command: git rev-parse --verify @{upstream}`

I was trying to change the channel to stable with

`flutter channel stable`

But got this error

`git: fatal: 'origin/stable' is not a commit and a branch 'stable' cannot be created from it Switching channels failed with error code 128.`

So it seems flutter installed on machine and saved in `Path` variable. But for some reason it does not see the version

When I run

`flutter doctor`

I see this

`Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): Failed to find the latest git commit date: VersionCheckError: Command exited with code 128: git -c log.showSignature=false log HEAD -n 1 --pretty=format:%ad --date=iso Standard out: Standard error: fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]' Returning 1969-12-31 19:00:00.000 instead. [!] Flutter (Channel unknown, 0.0.0-unknown, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1992], locale en-US) ! Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown on channel unknown at C:\flutter\flutter Currently on an unknown channel. Run`flutter channel`to switch to an official channel. If that doesn't fix the issue, reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install. Cannot resolve current version, possibly due to local changes. Reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install. ! Unknown upstream repository. Reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install. [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher) [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1) X cmdline-tools component is missing Run`path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details. X Android license status unknown. Run`flutter doctor --android-licenses `to accept the SDK licenses. See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details. [√] Chrome - develop for the web [√] Android Studio (version 2021.3) [√] VS Code (version 1.80.1) [√] Connected device (2 available) [√] Network resources ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383055/11760076

Comment: @offworldwelcome no its fixing just git of the project not flutter sdk itself

Comment: Did you verify the flutter folder installed in the PATH location? Perhaps there was a problem when upgrading flutter and the installation did not complete?